# Creating a shortcut to rename files

Tags: vba, shell, cmd, shortcut

Every week we get the same 5 excel files. I made a vba macro that copies the data from those files into the main excel sheet. However, in order for the code to work correctly, I call `"Workbooks("Workbook1").worksheet("sheet1").Activate`, where the Workbook1 file is actually called 2019-5-12_Workbook1 (which is given as that weeks date). All 5 files have this prefix with the date (eg. 2019-5-12_workbook2...etc). I'd like a way to rename all 5 of those files to the ones that don't have the date in front of them.

I've already found a way to mass rename the files using the ren command in cmd, but I want a faster way to rename them all at once using a simple shortcut on my desktop that runs the cmd command. If possible, I'd only have to save the original files to a folder on the desktop, click the shortcut, and have all 5 files renamed from 2019-5-12_Workbook1 to Workbook1, 2019-5-12_Workbook2 to Workbook2, etc, etc.

Comment: What's you ren command?

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please read [ASK]. SO isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and serious coding attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Hint: use [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split the file names at the underscore and rename with the 2nd part. While you don't see the extension in explorer you need it in cmd.

Comment: in the path that the files are in, I run ( ren "old file name" "new file name" )

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `ren` command in a .bat file and run it from your desktop.

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work, since the file names change each week. this will mean I will have to manually change the equations to the names within the command lines.

Comment: @D__, The contents of your .bat file should be like this:  
`ren *Workbook1.* Workbook1.*`
`ren *WorkBook2.* Workbook2.*`